# ExpandableListView not showing child views in fragment

Tags: android

I have an expandable listview. I have put some dummy data.but expandable listview not showing childviews.I have tried the code given bellow.

```
Elv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int len = mAdapter.getGroupCount();

        for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if(i != groupPosition) {
                list.collapseGroup(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Posted piece of code is not related to child view of expandable listview. You should post `getGroupView()` and `getChildView()` code. here.

Comment: please out full code hare

Comment: put your expandable `listview` `Adapter` class code

Answer (score 0):

`not showing childviews`. No that will not happen because you are collapsing all groups with `list.collapseGroup(i);`. Also the one that would expand because you touched it. Remove the code and you are done.